# Why Heatmap displays maps on wrong position?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heatmap

I'm using reactjs to draw heatmap. It works fine. But now I found that it displays the map on the wrong positions.

library: heatmap.js

code snippet:

```
points =[
        {x:1053,y:153,value:20}
    ]
    heat(){
        var heatmapInstance = h337.create({
          container: document.querySelector('.App')
        });
        heatInstance = heatmapInstance;
        var data = {
        min:0,
        max:5,
        data: this.points
        };
        heatmapInstance.setData(data);
    }
```

The problem here is,im giving position as 1053 and 153 but the heatmap circle displayed at (1140,290) checked coords using screenX,screenY parameters using onMouseMove function.What will be the reason ?

Thanks.

Comment: check the margin, padding ,etc.

Comment: @JosephD. i haven't applied any styles.

Comment: is the `data` in heat function array or object ??

Comment: @techguru it's array.